# Does Django Channels 1 & 2 compatible on Redis backend level?

Tags: django, redis, django-channels

I have an legacy Django app that uses Channels v1 with Redis backend. The new app I'm creating uses Channels v2 and should communicate with legacy app. Can it be done via the same channel layer Redis backend? I mean, can the new app send a message to an old app channel and get a response back?

UPD: No, they cannot.

Comment: v1 and v2 are not compatible.